# How to destroy all tooltips Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

Hi lets say we enable Tooltip everywhere take from this example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))

var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

After certain operation in the page, I want to dispose all the tooltips.

Since `tooltipList` is an array, I loop all the tooltip and dispose each tooltip

```
tooltipList.forEach(function (tooltip, index) {
      tooltip.dispose();
    });
```

This is working fine for me, but question is it the right way to dispose tooltip in Bootstrap 5?

In Bootstrap 4 the code much cleaner

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('dispose');
```

Thanks

Question

Comment: Using forEach to cycle through the tooltipList array appears to be the way to do it. If you want a cleaner line of code (appearance, not function), you could use an arrow function: `tooltipList.forEach((tooltip) => {tooltip.dispose()});`.

Comment: Thanks @RichDeBourke I wish someone will compile from Bootstrap 4 JS code to Bootstrap 5 JS code